# Laravel Pagination with appends() Error

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am new to Laravel and am using version 4.1.

I am attempting to query database using pagination and then run the results through the appends() function to add additional parameters to my URL.

Here is the code I am using

```
$query = DB::table('tableName');
$query->paginate(50);
$results = $query->get();
```

And that runs as desired. Now when I attempt to create the pagination list (Bootstrap default) and run the following code I get an error.

```
$pagination = $results->appends(array('key' => 'value'))->links();
```

This is the error I receive.

> Call to a member function appends() on a non-object

I know I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what...

Thanks in advance,
SC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the appends function, but you do have an error I can see.  Try changing

```
$query = DB::table('tableName');
$query->paginate(50);
$results = $query->get();
```

To...

```
$query = DB::table('tableName');

if(Input::has('someinput')) {
    $query->where('someinput', Input::get('someinput'));
}

if(Input::has('otherinput')) {
    $query->where('otherinput', Input::get('otherinput'));
}

$results = $query->paginate(50);
```

Once you run `paginate()`, an instance of `Paginator` is returned.  I don't see a `get()` method for `Paginator` though so I'm not sure how you weren't getting an error there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I originally had the query constructed the way you are stating, but I needed to add a dynamic where clause based on if a value was set. Because of that I changed the query to the format above. This allows me to use if(isset($value)) { $query->where(); } where with the way you've outlined, I could figure out how to do that.

Comment: Just call paginate after you are done building the query.  I'll modify my answer a bit for an example.